# Flutter Navigator 2.0 - dynamically set Page Title in browser tabs on Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

What I hope to accomplish is the Page title on the browser tab should dynamically change when I Navigate to a new page, the Page title continues to remain the same:

[Home page with 'home' as the Page title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKUyJ.png)

[Settings still has 'home' as Page title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byn7t.png)

I have attempted to use `SystemChrome.setApplicationSwitcherDescription` to change the Page title, something as follows:

```dart
SystemChrome.setApplicationSwitcherDescription(
        ApplicationSwitcherDescription(
      label: title,
      primaryColor:
          Theme.of(context).primaryColor.value, 
    ));
```

Here is a better example of the code (where the Page title doesn't change):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(SimpleDemoApp());
}

class SimpleDemoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const SimpleDemoApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SimpleDemoAppState createState() => _SimpleDemoAppState();
}

class _SimpleDemoAppState extends State<SimpleDemoApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Simple Demo App',
      routeInformationParser: SimpleRouteInformationParser(),
      routerDelegate: SimpleRouteDelegate(),
    );
  }
}

class DemoPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String text;
  final bool active;
  final ValueChanged<bool>? onChanged;
  DemoPage(
      {required this.title,
      required this.text,
      this.onChanged,
      this.active = false,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Attempting to change title here
    SystemChrome.setApplicationSwitcherDescription(
        ApplicationSwitcherDescription(
      label: title,
      primaryColor:
          Theme.of(context).primaryColor.value, 
    ));
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                text,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: onChanged != null,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      onChanged!(!active);
                    },
                    child: Text('Click Me!')),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class SimpleRoutePath {
  bool showSettings;
  bool showUnknown;

  SimpleRoutePath.home()
      : showSettings = false,
        showUnknown = false;

  SimpleRoutePath.settings()
      : showSettings = true,
        showUnknown = false;

  SimpleRoutePath.unknown()
      : showSettings = true,
        showUnknown = true;

  bool get isHomePage => showSettings == false && showUnknown == false;
}

class SimpleRouteInformationParser
    extends RouteInformationParser<SimpleRoutePath> {
  @override
  Future<SimpleRoutePath> parseRouteInformation(
      RouteInformation routeInformation) async {
    final uri = Uri.parse(routeInformation.location ?? '/');

    // Handle '/'
    if (uri.pathSegments.length == 0) {
      return SimpleRoutePath.home();
    }

    // Handle '/settings'
    if (uri.pathSegments.length == 1) {
      if (uri.pathSegments[0] == 'settings') return SimpleRoutePath.settings();
    }

    return SimpleRoutePath.unknown();
  }

  @override
  RouteInformation? restoreRouteInformation(SimpleRoutePath configuration) {
    if (configuration.showUnknown) return RouteInformation(location: '/404');

    if (configuration.showSettings)
      return RouteInformation(location: '/settings');

    if (configuration.isHomePage) return RouteInformation(location: '/');

    return null;
  }
}

class SimpleRouteDelegate extends RouterDelegate<SimpleRoutePath>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<SimpleRoutePath> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  bool settings = false;
  bool unknown = false;

  @override
  SimpleRoutePath? get currentConfiguration {
    if (unknown) return SimpleRoutePath.unknown();
    if (settings) return SimpleRoutePath.settings();

    return SimpleRoutePath.home();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: [
        MaterialPage(
            key: ValueKey('Home Page'),
            child: DemoPage(
              title: "Home",
              text: "Go to settings",
              onChanged: (value) {
                settings = true;
                notifyListeners();
              },
            )),
        if (unknown)
          MaterialPage(
            key: ValueKey('Unknown Page'),
            child: DemoPage(title: "Unknown", text: "404!"),
          )
        else if (settings)
          MaterialPage(
            key: ValueKey('Settings Page'),
            child: DemoPage(
                title: "Settings",
                text: "Go to 404",
                onChanged: (value) {
                  unknown = true;
                  notifyListeners();
                }),
          )
      ],
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        if (!route.didPop(result)) {
          return false;
        }

        // Go back to home
        unknown = false;
        settings = false;
        notifyListeners();

        return true;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(SimpleRoutePath configuration) async {
    if (configuration.showUnknown) {
      unknown = true;
      settings = false;
      return;
    }

    if (configuration.showSettings) {
      unknown = false;
      settings = true;
      return;
    }

    unknown = false;
    settings = false;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to dynamically change the Page Title?

Thanks in advance, to anyone who spends any time helping me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but to answer it, as it is for the web, you should use `SystemChrome` class just before return in the `build` method:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setApplicationSwitcherDescription(
        ApplicationSwitcherDescription(
      label: 'The title on each screen',
      primaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.value,
    ));
    return ...
  }
```